# How to fix the broken plastic of headphone/earphone wires?

Tags: headphones, plastics

This question is different from the one where the [metal wire](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/3816/how-do-you-stop-headphone-wires-from-breaking) breaks.

It's been a few years since I've used these earphones of my phone, and now the plastic is beginning to crack at multiple points, exposing the metal wire (but there is no problem with the functionality of the earphones. It's functioning fine).
[image]

I've tried wrapping cello-tape and insulation tape around it, but the tape never stays in position. It keeps sliding sideways, exposing the broken plastic and wire again.

Is the only solution to get a new pair of earphones or is there a way to fix the plastic.

Comment: use heat shrink wrapping

Comment: Electrical tape?

Comment: Electrical tape is the black wrapping you see in the pic. It doesn't stay in place. Heat shrink wrapping I've never tried, but I Googled it and it seems like it's meant for larger objects. Would you actually use it on earphone wires? The wire's plastic is breaking at multiple points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use heat shrink instead of tape. That won't slip around after it shrinks around the damaged area.

Answer (score 1):

what about usign this product that is like an epoxy, but bends.
https://sugru.com/

Comment: Looks good. Hope to see it available in all countries.